# Crystal oscillators of an STM32 microcontroller board

Tags: stm32, clock

I have the STM32F302R8 MCU board.l  Its user manual is [here](https://files.amperka.ru/datasheets/nucleo-usermanual.pdf).

There are two crystal oscillators on the board. X3 is missing and X1 seems to be used for the small debugger microcontroller (circled in red below):

[image]

In STM32CubeMX I can set external high speed oscillator as the main clock, but it seems X1 is used only for the debugger. If so, how come I can set the clock as HSE? **Does that mean this X1 can be used for the main microcontroller?** Is there a way to figure out this from the manual?

Clock configuration I can either select:

[image]

or:

[image]

In the above cases **is LSE connected to X3** which is missing? In the second case **is HSE the main system clock and connected to X1**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1724-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf) on p.24.

Excerpt from the respective page:

> There are two possible default configurations of the HSE pins, depending on the version of the STM32 Nucleo board hardware.

> The board version MB1136 C-01 or MB1136 C-02 is mentioned on the sticker, placed on the bottom side of the PCB.

> The board marking MB1136 C-01 corresponds to a board, configured as HSE not used.

> The board marking MB1136 C-02 (or higher) corresponds to a board, configured to use
> ST-LINK MCO as the clock input.